# AWS EMR import pyfile from S3

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm struggling to understand how to import files as libraries with pyspark.

Let's say that I have the following

**HappyBirthday.py**

```
def run():
    print('Happy Birthday!')
```

**sparky.py**

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import HappyBirthday
sc = SparkContext(appName="kmeans")

HappyBirthday.run()
sc.stop()
```

And both of them are stored in the same folder in S3.

How I make sure that, when I use

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster s3://<PATH TO FILE>/sparky.py
```

, HappyBirthday.py is also imported?

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to run sparky.py and use a function inside HappyBirthday.py, you can try something like this.

```
spark-submit \
--deploy-mode cluster --master yarn \
--py-files s3://<PATH TO FILE>/HappyBirthday.py \
s3://<PATH TO FILE>/sparky.py
```

Just remember that s3 does not have the concept of "folders", so you just need to provide the exact path of the files or the group of files.

In case you have a whole bunch of dependencies in your project, you can bundle them all up into a single .zip file with the necessary **init**.py files and you can import any of the functions inside the libraries.

For example - I have sqlparse library as a dependency, with a bunch of python file s inside it. I have a package zip file, like below.

```
unzip -l packages.zip
Archive:  packages.zip
        0  05-05-2019 12:44   sqlparse/
     2249  05-05-2019 12:44   sqlparse/__init__.py
     5916  05-05-2019 12:44   sqlparse/cli.py
...
      110  05-05-2019 12:44   sqlparse-0.3.0.dist-info/WHEEL
---------                     -------
   125034                     38 files
```

This is uploaded to S3 and then used in the job.

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --py-files s3://my0-test-bucket/artifacts/packages.zip s3://my-test-script/script/script.py
```

My file can contain imports like below.

```
import pyspark
import sqlparse # Importing the library
from pprint import pprint
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to use here is the `--py-files` argument for `spark-submit`.  From the [submitting applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) page in the Spark documentation:

> For Python, you can use the --py-files argument of spark-submit to add .py, .zip or .egg files to be distributed with your application. If you depend on multiple Python files we recommend packaging them into a .zip or .egg.

For your example, this would be:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --py-files s3://<PATH TO FILE>/sparky.py
```